# Cant read property from service in angular

Tags: angularjs, service

In this case console logged all properties

```
    app.controller("sgCtrl", function ($scope, $service)
    {
    var asd=service.getPerson();
    console.log(asd);
    }
```

But when im try to get some property its returned me undefined

```
...console.log(asd.person.Id)
```

My service

```
 function service($http, $q) {
  var service = {
    person:[]
  };

    service.getPerson = function (personId) {

    return $http.get('/P/GetP',
    {params:{personId:personId}}).success(function (res) {

       service.person = res.Person;
    });
};
```

Comment: Missing $? $service.getPerson();

Comment: @Damiano I always wonder if it's that simple, or if that just happens to be a typo in the question, good catch if so.

Comment: no there are no syntax error

Comment: Its working for all object ,but doesnt for property

Comment: {"Person":{"BirthDate":"11.11.2011","IsActive":true}

Comment: Well there is no Id property, so the error makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is 
1. $http.().success(function() {}) is asynchronous function. So service.person will be available only when control will come inside success callback handler.
2. You have not created service in the correct way.

You can try with below code:

### Service code

```
function service($http, $q) {
    this.getPerson = function (personId, successHandler) {

    $http.get('/P/GetP',
    {params:{personId:personId}}).success(function (res) {
       successHandler(res.Person);
    });
};

app.service('MyService', service);
```

### Controller Code

```
app.controller("sgCtrl", function ($scope, MyService) {
    function successHandler(person) {
        console.log(person.IsActive);     
    }

    MyService.getPerson('somePersonId', successHandler);
}
```

I believe it will resolve your issues.

Cheers!